# kibana 5 upload CSV

Tags: kibana, kibana-5

I am trying to use Kibana 5 to upload CSV.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-5-0-0-alpha4 as per this link - we have a provision to upload the CSV file in kibana 5.

I tried accessing to upload CSV as mentioned in the document as Management .. I am trying to look for UPLOAD CSV or adding some file.  [image]

Can anyone help with this? I am not seeing the provision to add a CSV file on top of it.

Comment: You're running on top of  `Elasticsearch 5.0.0-alpha4`?

Comment: yes.. @Kulasangar

Comment: But are you sure that the feature isn't exclusive for kibana-5-0-0-alpha4  only, since you're using `Kibana 5.0`? You should be having [Kibana 5.0.1](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana) as per the link you've provided in the Q.

Comment: thanks for that! I didnt notice that.

Comment: I did check Kibana 5.0.1 as well, upload CSV is not there in that too.

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/8497. Apparently they didn't think it was production ready. Real shame because I think it would work for 99% of the cases (as far as I fiddled around with it).

Answer (score 1):

As per the link you've provided in the question, the `Kibana` version seems to be [5.0.1](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana) in order to upload any CSV.

Comment: I did check Kibana 5.0.1 as well, upload CSV is not there in that too.

Comment: Are you getting the same ui level components in `Kibana 5.0.1` other than the csv feature? I mean according to the [screenshot](https://www.elastic.co/assets/blt8fa9980b520c705f/upload-csv.png).

Comment: it is not working for me still.. yeah! same UI components.